# Create parameterized keybindings

Tags: vim

I'd like to map `+Ngt` and `-Ngt` to `:tabnext N` and `:tabprev N`. I can create key bindings such as:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> +1gt :tabnext 1
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> +2gt :tabnext 2
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> +3gt :tabnext 3
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> +4gt :tabnext 4
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> +5gt :tabnext 5
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> +6gt :tabnext 6
...
```

but can I do it better? (Not that I really want to move "6 tabs ahead" since that would be much slower than just typing `Ngt`, but IMO it's only natural to ask this question for future reference.)

A great example would be `NG` command that jumps to line `N`. I highly doubt that Vim internally adds separate keybinding to each line we might possibly want to jump to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do better:

```viml
nnoremap <silent> gt @=":tabnext\n"<CR>
```

Then `6gt` will move 6 tabs ahead etc.  Using the expression register `=` is a trick to make a map repeatable by a number prefix.

On a side note: you can also do better by posting Vim-related questions to its own [home](https://vi.stackexchange.com/). :)

Comment: Right, I completely forgot about vim stackexchange. Thanks.